# Backup files at the end of the day

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system, windows

This is my first attempt at writing code that moves files at the end of the day, from my local work folder to an network archive.

The program works but, any tips, tricks, or ideas to make this code better would be most appreciated.

```
import shutil, os, datetime, time, sys

os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM FlashRen.exe') 

newFolderName = datetime.datetime.now()
newFolder = newFolderName.strftime('%m%d%Y')


src = ('C:\\AEC Work\\' + newFolder)
dst = ('\\\qnap01\\Data Service\\AARON\\' +
           newFolderName.strftime('%Y\\') +
           newFolderName.strftime('%m. %B\\').upper() + newFolder)

for file in os.listdir(src):
    src_file = os.path.join(src, file)
    dst_file = os.path.join(dst, file)
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing multiple imports on the same line from different modules is frowned upon by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style-guide.

It also recommends using `lower_case` for variable names and not `camelCase`.

You don't need `()` around variables when assigning, `src = 'C:\AEC Work\' + newFolder` is enough.

Since you are already using `os.path.join`, which is a good thing, you should use it throughout.

You can use `str.format` to get `"{:%m%d%Y}".format(datetime.datetime.now())` for the new folder name to make this slightly more compact.

```
import shutil
import os
import datetime
import time
import sys

os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM FlashRen.exe') 

now = datetime.datetime.now()
directory = "{:%m%d%Y}".format(now)

src = os.path.join('C:','AEC Work', directory)
backup_base = os.path.join('\qnap01', 'Data Service', 'AARON')
dst = os.path.join(backup_base, "{:%Y}".format(now),
                   "{:%m. %B}".format(now).upper(), directory)

for file in os.listdir(src):
    src_file = os.path.join(src, file)
    dst_file = os.path.join(dst, file)
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Graipher's excellent answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/145431/61966), I'd wrap everything inside some functions and call that from `__main__`. This way, you'll keep things even more obvious than they are now.

More, in the last 2/3 last lines, didn't you mean:

```
shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
```

?

Anyhow, there's how I'd further improve it:

```
import shutil
import os
import datetime


def kill_flashren_proc():
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM FlashRen.exe')


def get_current_time():
    return datetime.datetime.now()


def create_directory_name():
    return "{:%m%d%Y}".format(get_current_time())


def main():
    kill_flashren_proc()

    now = get_current_time()
    directory = create_directory_name()

    src = os.path.join('C:', 'AEC Work', directory)
    backup_base = os.path.join('\qnap01', 'Data Service', 'AARON')
    dst = os.path.join(backup_base, "{:%Y}".format(now), "{:%m. %B}".format(now).upper(), directory)

    for file in os.listdir(src):
        src_file = os.path.join(src, file)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst, file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that you also don't need `time` and `sys` modules anymore so you can take them out.